# JButton without function

Tags: java, modal-dialog, jbutton, actionlistener, jdialog

I got the problem that my buttons are not working. I have used JButtons before and hadn't had a problem with them before. Visually, the program looks as intended.

Can someone tell me why the button is not working? The class uses JDialog.

```
JButton cancel;

public CodeExample() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    add(cancel = new JButton ("Cancel"));
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setModal(true);
    setVisible(true);


    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The _last_ thing you should do is make the dialog visible.

Comment: oh. uhm, yea that fixed the problem ^_^ Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: Someone who knows more about Swing will eventually show up and explain why. I don't know enough to write an answer with an intelligible explanation, I just know it is a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419705/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas) already pointed out, the last thing you should do is to make the dialog visible.

The problem here are those two lines:

```
this.setModal(true);
this.setVisible(true);
```

If a dialog is modal, then `setVisible` will block until the dialog is not longer visible or disposed.

This means that everything after `setVisible` is executed after the user clicks on the red X to close the window. But at this point the dialog is not longer visible and you don't show the dialog again.

Comment: Also consider using a `JOptionPane`, it can do what you are doing here.

Comment: that was trivial to discover using the debugger, though.